# Two columns within mdframed frame

Tags: two-column, multicol, mdframed

I want to add a simple two-column text within `framed` frame. I tried `multicols` as

```
\begin{mdframed}
\setlength{\columnsep}{10pt}
  \begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{itemize}
     TEXT
    \end{itemize}
  \end{multicols}
\end{mdframed}
```

The problem is that when the text is long, it will start from the next page to fit the text within a page, though the frame is started from the current page.

Comment: That is not supported. I have no idea how to implement this feature.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I understand, but I think it is not impossible to find a trick to do so, if not making an adjustment to the `mdframed`.

Answer (score 3):

Since you only want a simple two-column text within a framed environment, try the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} %
\usepackage{framed,multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{framed}
\setlength{\columnsep}{10pt}
  \begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{itemize}
     \item test
     \item test
     \item test
     \item test
     \item test
     \item test
     \item test
     \item test
     \item test
     \item test
    \end{itemize}
  \end{multicols}
\end{framed}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the above still does not resolve the issue but it does break paragraphs beautifully.

Comment: I think the OP wants this to be able to work when there is longer text that spans multiple pages as `mdframed` allows for page breaks, but don't think that the `framed` allows for them.

Comment: @PeterGrill I would suppose so but I understand what the @ali is saying. I have the same problem with an `mdframed` environment of mine but haven't bothered to address it. If the answer is inappropriate or the if @ali does not agree with the answer I will delete it.

Comment: I would just suggest that you add a note that this won't work if the text needs to span a page break.