# Why are my margins ignored?

Tags: multicol, mdframed

Based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116809/shaded-multicols-ii/116939#116939) code, I added a title but now I face the problem that the margins are ignored when I use book or scrbook with the twoside option.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}


\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{-2pt}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}


\tikzset{titregris/.style = {draw=gray, thick, fill=white, text=black, rectangle, rounded corners, right, minimum height=.7cm}}

\makeatletter
\mdfdefinestyle{exercisestyle}{%
  outerlinewidth=1em,outerlinecolor=white,%
  leftmargin=-1em,rightmargin=-1em,%
  middlelinewidth=1.2pt,roundcorner=5pt,linecolor=gray,
  backgroundcolor=black!10,
  skipabove={0.2pt},
  innertopmargin=\baselineskip,
  needspace=3\baselineskip,
  frametitlefont=\sffamily\bfseries,
  singleextra={%
      \node[titregris,xshift=1cm] at (P-|O) %
         {~\mdf@frametitlefont{Text}\hbox{~}};
   },
  firstextra={%
      \node[titregris,xshift=1cm] at (P-|O) %
         {~\mdf@frametitlefont{Test}\hbox{~}};
   },
}
\makeatother



\makeatletter
\let\old@page@sofar\page@sofar
\let\old@box\box
\let\old@rlap\rlap
\def\page@sofar{%
\let\box\colorcolumn
\def\rlap{\let\box\old@box\old@rlap}%
\old@page@sofar
}
\def\colorcolumn#1{%
\ifnum#1=\mult@rightbox
\def\zz{\begin{mdframed}[skipabove={11.5pt},innertopmargin=\baselineskip,linecolor=gray,middlelinewidth=1.2pt,roundcorner=5pt,leftline=false,backgroundcolor=black!10]}%
\fi
\ifnum#1=\numexpr\mult@rightbox+2\relax
 \def\zz{\begin{mdframed}[style=exercisestyle, rightline=false]}%
\fi
\ifnum#1=\numexpr\mult@rightbox+4\relax
  \def\zz{\begin{mdframed}[skipabove={11.5pt},innertopmargin=\baselineskip,linecolor=gray,middlelinewidth=1.2pt,rightline=false,leftline=false,backgroundcolor=black!10]}%
\fi
       \kern\dimexpr-15pt\relax
        {\let\box\old@box\vtop{%
          \zz{%
           \hbox{\box#1\llap{\phantom p}}}%
           \end{mdframed}}}%
        \kern\dimexpr-15pt\relax
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\blindtext\blindtext
\end{multicols}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

What's going wrong here or better what does I need to do to make it working?

Comment: `leftmargin` and `rightmargin` may be responsible. Quoting the `mdframed` manual: »Many books are written in `twoside` mode. In those cases it’s better to set the margins related to the site. Instead of the explained options `leftmargin` and `rightmargin` you can work with the
options `outermargin` and `innermargin`.«

Comment: @cgnieder outermargin seems to have no influence and innermargin (only) shifts the left column under the right one. Any other ideas?

Comment: Indeed the options don't seem to work as expected... Maybe ask @MarcoDaniel about this?